# New-ish to Javascript. Having an issue trying to make an array of image objects from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Unsure if I am using the correct words to describe what I am attempting to do so its difficult to find an answer on here to my issue.

I have an array which is being generated from a text file in the form of tempData, and I want the array to reference my variables that are named the same as the strings when I reference them.

```js
var red = new Image(),
blue = new Image(),
bag = [],
tempData = '';

red.src='link to image location';
blue.src='link to image location';

tempData = "red\nblue";
bag = tempData.split("\n");

console.log(bag);
```

In the above snippet console.log(bag); returns an array of ["red", "blue"] I want it to return [red, blue] such that if I wanted bag[0] I could get red.src. From the examples I was looking at it mentioned window and eval both of which I was unable to make do what I wanted. Is there a way to make this work or am I just implementing them wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an images object and two property value pairs, one for each image. Then get the images by the key name in the bag array:

```js
var images = {},
bag = [],
tempData = '',
red = new Image(),
blue = new Image();

red.src='link to image location';
blue.src='link to image location';
images['red'] = red;
images['blue'] = blue;

tempData = "red\nblue";
bag = tempData.split("\n");

console.log(images[bag[0]].src);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.